# moving canvas box with arrows

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been trying to make a simple canvas box move with arrow keys. Here is the code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/stexplorer

And here also:

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 3;
  var xD = 0;
  var yD = 0;
  //var move;
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var ss = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 75
  };

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.rect(ss.x, ss.y, ss.width, ss.height);
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
   ctx.stroke();
  }

  function move() {
  x = ss.x + (xD * n);
  y = ss.y + (yD * n);
    ss.x = x;
    ss.y = y;
 }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
  xD = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xD;
  xD = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xD;
  yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yD;
  yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yD;
  e.preventDefault();
 });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
  xD = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xD;
  xD = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xD;
  yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yD;
  yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yD;
  e.preventDefault();
 });

  render();
  setInterval(move, .01);
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

This code should be doing the following:

- Whenever I press an arrow key, the box should move
- It would be great if I could make the canvas `width = "100vw"` and `height = "100vh"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render method will only be fired initially, you should add it as the last line of the move method, so the canvas will render the new position after every move.

```
function move() {
    x = ss.x + (xD * n);
    y = ss.y + (yD * n);
    ss.x = x;
    ss.y = y;
    render(); // add this line
}
```

Comment: I am a complete begginer in canvas, and pretty new in js, could you add code or something please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, click on result screen and than use keyboard arrow keys, also if this works for you mark my solution as answer, do post comment if you need anything else

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;
var x = 150;
var y = 100;
var WIDTH = 300;
var HEIGHT = 200;

function circle(x,y,r) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
}

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
}

function clear() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function doKeyDown(evt){
switch (evt.keyCode) {
case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed */
if (y - dy > 0){
y -= dy;
}
break;
case 40:  /* Down arrow was pressed */
if (y + dy < HEIGHT){
y += dy;
}
break;
case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressed */
if (x - dx > 0){
x -= dx;
}
break;
case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed */
if (x + dx < WIDTH){
x += dx;
}
break;
}
}

function draw() {
clear();
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
circle(x, y, 10);
}

init();
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty darn good! Upvote for that, but this is not at all what I was asking for, I might use it for future games though. Sorry.